# php form to html table in email

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple php quote form for my site. But I would like the values to appear in the email in separate lines. Currently they read across the page in one line separated by //.

This is how I would like then to appear. The boat option value come from a series of checkboxes that I have imploded.

Boat Options:

Rocket Launcher

Rod Holders

VHS Radio

How can I accomplish this in the form processor file? Please explain simply as I am strictly a front end coder.

My current email construction:

```
    //checkboxes
    $trailer = implode('  //  ', $_POST['checkboxes']);
    $options = implode('  //  ', $_POST['checkboxes1']);

    // Construct email body
    $body_message = 'Name: ' . $name . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Email: ' . $email . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Address: ' . $address . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Boat Purchase Date: ' . $purchase . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Trailer Option: ' . $trailer . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Boat Options: ' . $options . PHP_EOL;
    $body_message .= 'Motor Option: ' . $motor . PHP_EOL;
    $check_msg;
```

Comment: use <br> tag for line break.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh It won't work if the email header is not html. Better to use a plain EOL.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a form to PHP with post, the $_POST array contains the values of the form's input with input's names as keys. Therefore, I understand that all you checkboxes inputs for the boat are named "checkboxes1", which will make an array like $_POST['checkboxes1'][0], $_POST['checkboxes1'][1], etc.

When you implode $_POST['checkboxes1'], it creates a string of all checkboxes1 values. To show them on separated lines, just replace the separator ' // ' in your implode with a line break element such as BR (if your email is html) or PHP_EOL:

```
$options = implode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['checkboxes1']);
```